# Can I pay my USCIS fee after I enter US?

Tags: visas, usa

I am entering US under diversity visa and my visa duration is only 10 days. I have to enter US before that. I am entering 2 days before expiration. However they have instructed me to pay the USCIS fee online before I enter US. I have less idea on how I can pay online from here. Can I pay it in the airport or after I get there where my friends will help me. Will they let me enter US and start my green card processing without paying the fee?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can pay after entering.  Try searching a bit before posting questions.

http://www.uscis.gov/uscis-elis/e-filing-using-uscis-elis/paying-uscis-immigrant-fee-uscis-elis/uscis-immigrant-fee